# how to properly include source files for jasmine-node test runner

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using `jasmine` spec library along with `jasmine-node` runner for node.js. What is the right way to run the tests (the command in cli) that both includes source files and the spec files?

I've got a `lib` directory with the sources I want to include and the `unit.spec.js` that includes the tests. When I do the following, I get an error:

```
Tomasz.Ducin@WAWLT548 MINGW64 ~/Development/json-schema-faker/json-schema-faker (master)
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node lib unit.spec.js --noStackTrace --captureExceptions
F.

Failures:

  1) A suite contains spec with an expectation
    Message:
      ReferenceError: booleanGenerator is not defined

Finished in 0.007 seconds
2 Tests, 1 Failures, 0 Skipped
```

The `booleanGenerator` is defined in `lib` directory - but somehow it doesn't get loaded... dunno why.

Is the CommonJS `require` function the right way? Are the paths I pass in cli separate during jasmine runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory you pass in via the command prompt to jasmine-node is the folder where your specs are kept.

So yes, you will need to `require` the additonal functions you have defined in your lib directory in your spec files.

There's a good article [here](https://blog.codeship.com/jasmine-node-js-application-testing-tutorial/) where the traditional calculator project is built and you can see how the calculator functions are pulled in with `require`.